# Rest service sercurity

Tags: c#, security, rest

I have various c# rest services performing normal CRUD tasks on a database,

For example, I have a rest service to add a customer to my customers database table which will expect XML as indicated below,

```
<CreateCustomerRequest>
    <Name>Customer name</Name>
    <Surname>Customer surname</Surname>
</CreateCustomerRequest>
```

Anyone that knows the URL and the proper XML structure can therefore call the rest service and insert a customer into my database. What is the best way to make sure that unauthorized inserts are not performed? Perhaps a key send with the request calculated as MD%([name field] + [surname field] + [shared client/server key]??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Basic Authentication with your REST service.
Each call will need to send the auth information, or the call will fail with a 401.

Basically, the following needs to be appended to the content header of the request:

```
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4x
```

where YWRtaW46YWRtaW4x is base64 encoded username:password

You could also implement SSL and have your client send along a certificate with each request if you need that level of security.

Do not attempt to invent your own security unless you're an expert in that area.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# just use the built in Asp.Net authentication providers.

You can use any type of authentication asp.net supports or you can even roll your own provider.

It is always better to use what a framework supports.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733071.aspx